ParserError : While loading the dataframe in pandas
# Load the DataFrame
df = pd.read_csv("/content/data.csv", encoding='unicode_escape')
df

I am getting the following error:
ParserError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-11-5c1453a4783b> in <cell line: 2>()
      1 # Load the DataFrame
----> 2 df = pd.read_csv("/content/data.csv", encoding='unicode_escape')
      3 df
8 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx in pandas._libs.parsers.raise_parser_error()

ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 8 fields in line 25066, saw 11

How to resolve this?
I tried using encoding_errors="latin", encoding="latin", but nothing worked.

I don't believe specifying encoding with solve your issue. It seems to be a delimiter issue. Try specifying a delimiter with sep =  in your pd.read_csv(sep = {something} )

Have a look at line 25066 of your csv. Apparently, it has 10 commas, while up to that line, your lines have 7 commas (hence: 8 fields). Either fix it, and try again, or you can have a look at the on_bad_lines parameter for pd.read_csv.

you have incorrect row in file and you have to fix it. First you could read it line by line as normal text file and display line 25066 and few lines nearby. Maybe you have to only skip this line. Or maybe you append wrong data to file and now it is incorrect. OR maybe you use wrong tool to create CSV and it did't use " " to keep text with , as single item - and now this , makes problem - and this may need to correct code which create this file.

df = pd.read_csv("/content/data.csv", on_bad_lines="skip")
'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xa3 in position 79780: invalid start byte
I am getting is error!!
